# How do I provide a cypher query to neography ruby gem to search by relationships and date property?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neography, graphenedb

I am looking at the following:

https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/wiki/Scripts-and-queries

I have tried to come up with the value for "query" which will return the following:

- nodes that have a relationship `workingOn`
- created Date is yesterday (I used an integer of epoch time since it didn't seem like there was a Date type?)
- return the property `value`

I tried:

```
start n=node(id) # where id is the reference node
match n-[:workingOn]-()
where has(n.date < Date.now.to_i and n.date > Yesterday.to_i) # yesterday is a Date for yesterday
return n
```

**Solved:**
I got the insight from the question I marked as having solved it, but what I did was create a query string and used interpolation to populate it with the values needed.  E.g. `query = "Match (n) -[#{relationship}]-(n2)....etc`

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? It is a old syntax, not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using antiquated Cypher syntax. If you are using a recent version of neo4j (3.1+) and have the appropriate [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) plugin installed, the following should work. (I assume that the `id` parameter is passed when making the query. If it isn't, replace `$id` with the actual ID value.)

```
WITH timestamp() AS now
MATCH (n)
WHERE ID(n) = $id AND
  (n)-[:workingOn]-() AND
  apoc.date.convert(apoc.date.convert(now, 'ms', 'd') - 1, 'd', 'ms') < n.date < now
RETURN n;
```

It uses the `timestamp()` function to get the current epoch time (in milliseconds), and uses the APOC function [apoc.date.convert](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_conversion_of_timestamps_between_different_time_units) twice to get the epoch time for the *start* of yesterday.

It also moves the `(n)-[:workingOn]-()` pattern to the `WHERE` clause so that for each `n` only a single row is generated, even when that `n` has multiple `workingOn` relationships.

(The `RETURN` clause would actually be `RETURN n.value` if you wanted to return the `value` property of the `n` node.)

[UPDATE]

GrapheneDB supports plugins like APOC. [See their documentation](http://docs.graphenedb.com/docs/stored-procedures).

To search by a native neo4j ID, you need to know the ID value first. You may need to perform another query first to get it. Note, however, that it may be better for you to assign and use your own IDs instead of the native IDs, since the latter can be recycled and used for new nodes if the original is deleted.

Comment: how do I plug in APOC?  I am using Graphene DB?  Is there another way to do it without it?

Comment: also, quick related question: the documentation says that the node ID's are ephemeral, so I would need to search for the client ID first to assign the value $id?

Comment: Thanks, will do @cybersam

Comment: I used your idea and what I did was create a query-string, and allowed Ruby interpolation using `#{}` to populate with the correct values.  Your idea gave me the insight to solve for it.

Comment: One very minor suggestion, a slightly-nicer version of the date conversion for the start of yesterday is: `apoc.date.convert(apoc.date.convert(now, 'ms', 'd') - 1, 'd', 'ms')`.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Excellent suggestion. Incorporated.